# Possibility to remove Parse.User.current() storing in localStorage

Tags: reactjs, parse-platform, local-storage

Is it possible to remove the object storing automatically in localStorage upon user logged in? Since this is in their documentation.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Parse.User.logOut()`](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/3.1.0/Parse.User.html#.logOut) does this automatically but I suppose you are looking for a manuel way to do it.

Information of current user stores in `localStorage` as "Parse/APP_ID/currentUser"

`APP_ID` is the key you use when you initialize your Parse SDK

```
Parse.initialize("APP_ID", "JAVASCRIPT_KEY");
```

You can use `removeItem()` method in localStorage.

```
removeItem("Parse/APP_ID/currentUser")
```

If you want to do it with every login

```
Parse.User.logIn("myname", "mypass").then(user=>{
localStorage.removeItem("Parse/APP_ID/currentUser");
})
```